# Killing hidden OS X applications / Parallels 5 installer problem

Tags: macos, parallels

I'm trying to upgrade from Parallels 3, to 5. However on stage 6 of the installer I am told to:

> Quit the following applications:
>   Parallels Desktop for Mac

However, 'Parallels Desktop for Mac' isn't running! It's not in the Dock, or listed in Activity Monitor.

Is it running as a hidden process or service somewhere? How do I find it and kill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal window, Have you tried running

> ps aux | grep

After the **grep** type in a possible Parallels process keyword, if that does not work you may have to just use the ps aux command and weed out the possible processes.

Once you have the processes that are causing the issue, use the **killall** "process name" command or **kill -9** "PID"

Comment: I had tried this already, but weirdly got nothing back. On trying again it works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Activity Monitor, found at `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`, to see and kill any process running on your Mac. You may need to set it the `Show` popup menu to `All Processes` if this is the first time you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the last resort might be to [un-install version 3 manually](http://kb.parallels.com/4709), but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Besides which, finding the hidden application still interests me.

Answer (score 0):

*Sigh* - Reboot solved the problem.

Comment: ... and yes - I do talk to myself a lot....  ;)